# Transitions- your form

Tags: html, css

Code for my form to show transition. It is a simple form which appears on web page.

```
input[type=text], select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        input[type=password], select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        input[type=submit] {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        input[type=submit]:hover {
            background-color: black;
        }     
form{margin: 0 auto; 
             width:300px;
             border: 2px solid black;
             background-size:50px; 
             border-radius:12px;
             padding:12px; 
             transition: width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
        }
        form:hover{
            width: 400px;
            height: 250px;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
            transform: rotate(3600deg);
        }
```

MY Form looks like this on webpage-when i hover my mouse over it it does some 360. turns and enlarges a little.

[image]
What I want is that a box saying login to appear and when i hover my mouse over it the login text disappears and it transforms to the above like form. Is there a way for doing something like this.How can i do this?

Comment: I really advise you to not put animations like that on your webpage, It makes it seem unprofessional.

Comment: Can you please create a working fiddle?

Comment: It is not for a real webpage right now i am learning html so i am trying all kinds of different things i can do in it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hvev2jLc/